# Clojure realize vector of futures with timeout

Tags: java, asynchronous, clojure, completable-future

I am interfacing with a Java API that returns a `CompletableFuture`.
Now if I have an array of these `[cf1 cf2 cf3 …]`, how can I give them *all* one second to finish, and collect whatever they have produced after one second?

Something like:

```
  (def vec-of-cf [cf1 cf2 cf3])

  (get-all vec-of-cf 1000 ::timeout)

  ;; no more than 1 second later, I should have my vector of realized CompletableFuture, possibly holding a `::timeout` value if they did not have time to finish
```

I think this is akin to Scala `flatmap` (?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might use [`CompletableFuture.allOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) to obtain a single completable future you can block on to wait only as long as needed for all of them to complete or timeout (so possibly wait shorter than the timeout - all tasks up to one second, not necessarily after one second) and then iterate over original futures to obtain their values if they are done:

```
(def vec-of-cf [cf1 cf2 cf3])

(let [all-of (CompletableFuture/allOf (into-array vec-of-cf))]
  (try
    (.get all-of timeout)
    (catch java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException e))
  (->> vec-of-cf
       (filter #(.isDone %))
       (map #(.get %))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
(defn get-all [vec-of-cf timeout timeout-val]
 (Thread/sleep timeout)
 (mapv #(if (future-done? %) (deref %) timeout-val) vec-of-cf))
```

This code could be also modified to cancel not finished future (if it's required)